# Android emulator on apple M1 giving INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE most of the time

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, apple-m1

I'm trying to run android emulator on M1 and the emulator barely fits 1 of the apps im working on.

When i try to run my react native project i usually get `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`

I haven't installed any other apps on the emulator and all the pre-installed apps cannot be uninstalled.

Any idea how can i free up some storage space on android emulator ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Managed to fix it by following these steps :

1. click on the small arrow next to my emulator in avd manager and select `Show on Disk`

[image]

3. Open `config.ini`

[image]

4. find `disk.dataPartition.size={some number}` and change it to `disk.dataPartition.size=4000MB`
5. delete all .img files

here's the current storage

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, the solution was:
**increasing the space + cold boot.**

Just increasing the space was not working even doing a wipe, I increased the space a bunch of times lol but only worked when I did a cold boot.